# jQuery ready() calling directly, with a custom parameter

Tags: jquery, html, css

Im using several external JS files. Each file has this:

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
    //
});
```

so when page loaded, they can initialize themselves. But this time I need to do it manually, with passing a parameter (so call ready() of document, with a parameter) how to do that?

Comment: jQuery(document).ready(function($) { // Code using $ as usual goes here. });

Answer (score 1, accepted):

can you try this? didn't tested :P :

```
 var param = "hey";

    $(document).ready(function(param)
    {
        alert(param);
    });
```

or better:

```
 var param = "hey";

        $(function(param)
        {
            alert(param);
        });
```

Answer (score 2):

You can't. Document ready is fired by the browser when the DOM is ready, you can't trigger it yourself.

However you could place your code into a function which is called on ready, and you can then call that at any time after load you require. Something like this:

```
$(function() {
    doSomething("foo"); // onload

    $("#myElement").click(function() { doSomething("bar") }); // onclick of element
});

function doSomething(text) {
    alert(text);
};
```

Comment: is there any other event I can trigger by myself, and if I dont do that, it triggers standalone?

Answer (score 1):

```
var foo = function() { alert('!'); };

(function(d, f) {
    f();
})(document, foo);
```